# Circular image with RoundedBitmapDrawable is pixelated

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is what I am doing

```
public static RoundedBitmapDrawable getRoundedBitmap(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap){
    RoundedBitmapDrawable roundBitMap = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(res,bitmap);
    roundBitMap.setCornerRadius(Math.max(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()) / 1.25f);
    return roundBitMap;
}
```

It gives me a circular image but its pixelated on the circle's edge. Any idea how to make it smooth ? Or should I use an older technique ?

Comment: If you set a regular ImageView is the imgae correctly displayed?

Comment: it sounds like an aliasing problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you just need to invoke `roundBitMap.setAntiAlias(true);`